# Migrate multiple Azure Devops repo into one Azure Devops repo

Tags: devops, repo

Please can someone highlight how to migrate multiple Azure Devops repositories into one or two repo within the same Azure Devops project? All the Folders contain multiple subfolders and hence need to import all these repos into at least only 2 or 3 repos.

Answer (score 0):

[image]if the question is how to migrate between repos in azure devops
the answer is : in the top navbar in your project -> click on repository name ->
the drop down list will have other repositories , click on repository name to navigate